# Set up SSH tunnel with PgAdmin 4

Tags: ssh-tunnel, pgadmin-4

I am new to pgAdmin and to SSH tunnels. I am trying to establish a connection to a postgres DB with SSH tunnel. I am on Windows 10. I am given the following instructions (I changed all the names and ports in the below)

**Add the following to your SSH config (~/.ssh/config):**

```
Host prod
  Hostname myorg.org.uk
  User sshusername
  IdentityFile idef.pem
  LocalForward 9999 localforward.amazonaws.com:8888
```

**Now you can tunnel your way through to PostgreSQL:**

```
ssh -N prod
```

**And now psql et al can connect (You must open a new Terminal window while the SSH tunnel is running):**

```
psql -h localhost -p 9999 -U connectionusername -d dproduction
```

I am also given the `dproduction` database password for the database I am trying to connect to: `dproduction_pwd`

I don't understand where everything goes in pgAdmin. I did the following:

Create-Server:
Name = test

[image]

Connection:
Host Name/Address: localhost
Prot: 9999
Maintenance database: postgres
username: connectionusername

[image]

SSH Tunnel:
Tunnel host: myorg.org.uk
Tunnel post: 9999
username: sshusername
Identity file: C:\idef.pem
Password: dproduction_pwd

[image]

I must be doing something wrong, as I don't use LocalForward from the ssh config above, where does this go? putting it in Tunnel host does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to use SSH tunnel to access my database with Windows 10 SSH and PGAdmin SSH Tunnel. It did take a while. pgAdmin's document isn't very clear on this. Here's the difference I found:

When setting SSH tunnel with Windows 10 SSH, you need to forward a local port (9999 in your case) to the remote port (8888).

In pgAdmin, that local port is no longer needed. My guess is since it already knows you want to access which service through which tunnel, it takes care of the local port in the background. That tunnel port, in the most common cases, should be the SSH port 22.

My suggested changes to your current setting would be:

1. in `SSH Tunnel` tab, set Tunnel port to 22
2. in `Connection` tab, set Port to 8888

This should work.